# Is it unethical for SE users with more than 40K rep to leave without donating their rep?

Tags: discussion

1. Let me know if I'm wrong, but  [25K](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=all) of reputation unlocks all privileges, and is the maximum reputation level that can be accomplished.
2. I picked 40K as the cutoff for this question, as I acknowledge that users want to conserve these privileges.
3. I'm assuming that these users won't be returning to the site. Thus most of their "wealthy" reputation will be useless.

I'm thinking of users like [Arturo Magidin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/742/arturo-magidin) who has 270,960 reputation. He was "[l]ast seen 2 hours ago". His profile emblazons that

> I remain "gone for the foreseeable future" from math.SE, tex.SE, and meta.SE. Though I may very occasionally post a comment or an answer, these do not signify a desire to re-start my heavy prior participation.
>
> Please do not send me private e-mail to call my attention to comments, questions, or other matters related to those sites. Thank you. Also, as I no longer participate in those sites, **I do not wish to be sent, by private e-mail, questions that you can just as well ask on those sites**. I would have thought it was obvious, but apparently I need to say so explicitly.

Thus before quitting, ought such users not donate some of their rep, or at least offer to do this?

I don't need to panegyrize the advantages of donating rep, rather than hoarding this rep or wealth. In a few words, donating rep can capacitate  impecunious users to contribute, like by awarding bounties on underrated questions, and gaining privileges.

Comment: Maybe is best suited for "meta" ...

Comment: Have to agree with Mauro, this seems more like a meta question. In particular the meta sites of the SE's to which such user is abdicating.

Comment: You might as well ask, regardless of leaving, whether it's unethical for users with very high rep to not donate rep. But since donating via bounties takes a substantial amount of time (you have to find appropriate questions, can only 'donate' so much at a time, etc.), I don't see why anyone should be compelled to spend their free time doing this.

Comment: SE rep is not a finite resource, it is fictitious, so it is not like somebody hoarding it deprives somebody else of anything. And users can contribute without much rep, which is supposed to provide the psychological incentive. Showering cheap rep may well interfere with this function. Besides, "donate" it to whom? To award bounties intelligently they'll have to stay active instead of quitting. Whatever the issues with underrated questions it is the active users and SE itself that have to deal with them.

Comment: *Is it unethical for SE users with more than 40K rep to leave without donating their rep?* No.

Comment: It’s weird, it’s like a strange kind of deja vu. Every new site I visit I find some new account you’ve created, disconnected from all the others, but still you. Why do you create so many accounts? What’s the point?

Comment: it may be irritating but 'unethical' strikes me as too harsh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any user with [15 reputation or more can up-vote](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) a post *if they want to*. When doing this the one who made the post receives reputation points.

This is one way almost any user, not just those with very high reputation, can award reputation to others.

Those users who say they are leaving may one day change their minds and want to return. So the assumption in point 3 does not seem reasonable to make.